# Upload/Create file in SharePoint Online Document Library using MS Graph

Tags: sharepoint-online

I am trying to create a file with sample content in a SharePoint Online Document Library using MS Graph.

MS Graph API:
[https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site-id}/drives/{drive-id}/root:/filename.txt:/content](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/%7Bsite-id%7D/drives/%7Bdrive-id%7D/root:/filename.txt:/content)

Can anyone please explain how to upload and what will be request body for this API ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In postman, we could upload the file like this:

choose binary in the Body:

[image]

Comment: If my answer helps you, you could accept it :)